# Array producing incorrect values after showing correct values

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This code is part of a larger piece of code of a minMax function to produce all possible game states of a tic-tac-toe game, which will calculate a score based on number of turns it takes to win or lose and choose the largest scoring turn, which will then move to that spot.

My issue is creating the new game states base on the open spots on the board.

I created a dynamic 2d array that holds the number of new possible states, and the it's new game state that will be then used in scanning for a win/loss, or recursing back into minMax to repeat the process.

```
for( int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for ( int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        if(gBoard[i][j] == 0)
        {
            turnCount++;    //getting number of possible new game states to create

        }
    }
}

int** newState = new int*[turnCount]; //creates pointer array that for number of possible newStates

for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    newState[i] = new int[i];
}
```

I then take that newState[][] array and populate it with the new game states as above with the code below.

```
//Creating new game states based on all new possible moves



for( int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for ( int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        count=0;
        if(gBoard[i][j] == 0)
        {
            for( int x=0; x<3; x++)
            {
                for( int y=0; y<3; y++)
                {
                    newState[nState][count] = gBoard[x][y];
                    //newState[nState][tick] = player; //first empty place filled with "player" peice

                    //cout<<newState[nState][count];
                    count++;

                }
            }

            cout<<endl;
            for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
            {
                cout<<newState[nState][i]; //Filled correctly with the current game state
                //With nState 6 starting from 0
            }
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"nState: "<<nState;
            cout<<endl;
            nState++;
        }
        tick++;
    }
}
```

Not as of right now I'm not filling the new game states with their respective move, as I'm trying to figure out my current issue.

The code above when creating the new nState produces the following results in terminal when run,

```
100000001
nState: 0

100000001
nState: 1

100000001
nState: 2

100000001
nState: 3

100000001
nState: 4

100000001
nState: 5

100000001
nState: 6
```

As you see, newState[nState][] produced the correct number of nStates and filled those nStates with the gameBoard values.

However, right after I do this and call newState[][] again, I get a a random 1 value in the fourth space. The code to show nState[nState][i] is as follows.

```
nState = 0;
cout<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    cout<<newState[nState][i]; //nState at 0, same as first iteration from the top of the start of the main and it doesn't work. i is reset, I'm getting the iterations for one nState that is in the array and the value of nState [i], yet it's producing giberish.

}
cout<<endl<<"nState: "<<nState<<endl;
```

When the code runs the terminal spits this out for newState[nState][i];

```
100010001
nState: 0
```

I'm completely stumped. I see nothing wrong in the code that would suddenly produce such different results. I tested to make sure nState is staying correct when all the loops are happening, and as you see it is. If anyone one has any idea I would love to here it, as I believe I have the logic of my function correct for everything else, but this is producing a major roadblock in the code.

Comment: `newState[i] = new int[i];` :  Did you really intend for  *zero* `int` in the `[0]` column, *one* in `[1]` column etc .. ?

Comment: I just fixed it, instead of trying to dynamically make an array based on possible turnes, I just created a newState[9][9] array to have space for all possible nStates, instead of messing with this.

Comment: I now see what you're talking about and fixed the issue brought up by you and  The Paramagnetic Croissant

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, got rid of the dynamic allocation of the newState array and just created a static array that can hold 9 newStates, the max number of newStates for the board.

Comment: `new int[i]` allocates `i` ints. You rather want `new int[3]`.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't catch that. I should be spanked.